# Is 11GB folder size normal for npx create-react-app my-app?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npx

I am new to web development and currently trying to learn React.

I created three different folders but each of them are at least 11GB:

```
npx create-react-app my-app1
npx create-react-app my-app2
npx create-react-app my-app3
```

From my reading, node_modules is huge but why do mine uses 11GB?

What should I do to reduce the default node_modules size?

Comment: Yeah that's really big, did you install any other dependencies or have any images in there?

Comment: Can you provide more details? I just did a completely fresh install of a CRA app and my node modules folder is only 309MB.